# R - filter row if id column is unique or, when id is duplicated, the row with least NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(123)

testdf <- data.frame(id = c(123,124,125,125,126,126,126,127,128,129,130),
                 var01 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var02 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var03 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var04 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var05 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var06 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var07 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var08 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var09 = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)),
                 var10  = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", NA), 11, TRUE)))

testdf
    id var01 var02 var03 var04 var05 var06 var07 var08 var09 var10
1  123     B     B     C  <NA>     A     A  <NA>     C  <NA>     C
2  124  <NA>     C  <NA>     A     A     A  <NA>     B     A     C
3  125     B     C     C     B     A  <NA>  <NA>     A     A     B
4  125  <NA>     A     C  <NA>     B  <NA>     B     A     C     B
5  126  <NA>  <NA>     C     A     B     B  <NA>     C     B  <NA>
6  126     A     A     C     B  <NA>     C     C     B     C     B
7  126     C     A     B     A     A     A     C  <NA>     B  <NA>
8  127  <NA>     B     A     A     B     B     A     A     A  <NA>
9  128     C  <NA>  <NA>     B  <NA>     B     B     B  <NA>     C
10 129     B  <NA>  <NA>     B     A  <NA>     A  <NA>     A     B
11 130  <NA>     C     C     B     C     B     B  <NA>     B     A
```

I want to filter rows based on 2 conditions:

1) Rows with a unique id.

2) When ID is duplicated, I want to keep the row with the least NAs in that row.

My desired output exists of all rows except 4, 5 and 7. 
You can assume the minimum NAs in a row for each id occurs only once (so 2 for id 125 and 1 for 126 in the example).

I prefer a base R or dplyr solution.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
testdf %>% 
  mutate(NAs = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(NAs == min(NAs)) %>% 
  select(-NAs) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Or

```
testdf %>% 
  arrange(id, rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Comment: @Renu Out of curiosity, what if you had any ties for least? The choice may be subjective, I suppose.

Comment: The add a `%>% slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I asked this question years ago, when I was less experienced with R. In case it is ever useful to anyone, this might be the shortest solution:

```
testdf %>% 
  arrange(id, rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T)
```